# join two mysql queries based on parameters

Tags: sql, mysql

i have two queries, querying the same table, but based on different parameters,

i then need to mush these two result sets together based on certian parameters

```
//get initial text
Q1
SELECT 
campaign_id AS campaign_id, 
from_number AS mobile,
received_msg AS join_txt,
date_received AS join_txt_date
 FROM received_txts WHERE action_id = 4 AND msg_link_id = id;

//get final text
Q2
SELECT 
campaign_id AS campaign_id, 
from_number AS mobile,
received_msg AS final_txt,
date_received AS final_txt_date
 FROM received_txts WHERE action_id = 4 AND msg_complete_id = id;

/join these two queries on
Q2.msg_link_id = Q1.id AND Q2.campaign_id = Q1.campaign_id AND Q2.from_number = Q1.from_number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  Q1.campaign_id AS campaign_id, 
  Q1.from_number AS mobile,
  Q1.received_msg AS join_txt,
  Q1.date_received AS join_txt_date,
  Q2.received_msg AS final_txt,
  Q2.date_received AS final_txt_date
FROM received_txts Q1 JOIN received_txts Q2
  ON Q2.msg_link_id = Q1.id
    AND Q2.campaign_id = Q1.campaign_id
    AND Q2.from_number = Q1.from_number
WHERE Q1.action_id = 4
  AND Q2.action_id = 4
  AND Q1.msg_link_id = Q2.id
  AND Q2.msg_complete_id = Q2.id
```

Comment: I would have used a sub query on action_id=4, but other than that, I'd go with this.  Any reason you didn't?

Comment: Subquery? I don't know, why? Would it be faster?

Answer (score 0):

use a virtual table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t1
JOIN ( select .. ) AS t2
ON ( t1.foo = t2.foo )
```

Comment: I tried doing

    SELECT
    t1.campaign_id  AS campaign_id, 
    t1.from_number  AS mobile,
    t1.received_msg  AS join_txt,
    t1.date_received AS join_txt_date,
    t2.final_txt  AS final_txt,
    t2.final_txt_date AS final_txt_date
    FROM received_txts AS t1
    

(part 2 below)

Comment: JOIN (
        SELECT 
        id   AS id,
        msg_complete_id AS msg_complete_id,
        msg_link_id AS msg_link_id,
        campaign_id  AS campaign_id,
        from_number  AS mobile,
        received_txt  AS final_txt,
 date_received  AS final_txt_date
 WHERE msg_complete_id = id
  ) AS t2
ON ( t1.msg_link_id = t1.id AND t2.msg_link_id = t1.id AND t2.campaign_id = t1.campaign_id AND t2.from_number = t1.from_number AND t2. )

but i get: 
error in your SQL syntax;  near 'where msg_complete_id = id
  ) AS t2
ON ( t1.msg_link_id = t1.id and t2.msg_li'